# shared library with link error to client function

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I wrote a shared library with a class like this:

```
// lib.h
class LibClass {
    template<typename T>
    static void foo () {
        T *tmp = new T();
        tmp->bar();
    }
};
```

And I used the lib somewhere else with defined class as:

```
//client.cpp
class C {
public:
    void bar() { cout<<"bar"<<endl; }
};

int main () {
    LibClass::foo<C>();
    return 0;
}
```

I got the error `undefined reference to 'C::bar()'`

Comment: Is that *exactly* what's in lib.h and client.cpp?  The code you present would not give that one specific error.

Comment: It a simplified version of the actual situation. However, the problem is solved now. The code I posted here is *correct*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect you're using a *nix linker, and that you list the object files (to the compiler/linked as `client.o` and then `lib.so`. But unfortunately when the linker sees client.o it already can see there's no reference to `C::bar` and doesn't emit any code for it.

You need to either use an object group, or list `client.o` twice, both before *and* after your library on the link command line.